# Can Three.js Y coordinates go down instead of up?

Tags: three.js

Is there an easy way to change the Three.js coordinate system so that Y values increase as they move down the screen instead of up?

I have to write some code that works in both SVG and Three.js. It'd be nice if I didn't need to keep flipping the Y coordinates. (And the code already works in SVG, so I'd prefer to stick to SVG's increasing-Y-means-down convention.)

Comment: You can orient the camera - see [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814488/webgl-opengl-rotate-camera-according-to-device-orientation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. three.js is based on a right-handed coordinate system. If positive-y were in the 'down' direction, then the coordinate system would be a left-handed one.

You are going to have to continue to adapt at the application layer.

three.js r.57

Comment: If Y were to go downward, that doesn't change the handedness (however object rotating on Y would appear to rotate the opposite direction). Changing handedness would (should) be an additional option.